# How to use Json.NET with standard (like) OData service

Tags: c#, json.net, odata

I try to use Json.NET for consuming an OData (like) service. My data structures have collection properties.
However all those properties are wrapped in a property called 'results' by my service. Even the main query which returns with a collection of the entities are wrapped into a root property called results.

Although I am not an OData expert I think this is pretty much a standard because if I try to send an object graph for update, and omit this 'results' wrapper around say a int collection type property then I got an error message from the server "A collection was found without the 'results' property. In OData, each collection must be represented as a JSON object with a property 'results'"

So I understand the server error message, and I also know how to workaround this. Of course I can mimic this object graph in my C# object model, but after writing the 101st wrapper in my object model it tends to be boring, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

My question is there an out of the box solution how to deal with this result property, and make it transparent? If this is a 'standard' I suppose not I am the first who are facing this task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can just write one and use it everywhere

```
public class OData<T> where T : IEnumerable
{
    public T results { get; set; }
}

public class X
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    public OData<List<int>> List { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new X()
        {
            Prop = "test",
            List = new OData<List<int>> {results = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}}
        };
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x));
    }
}
```